# Persisting nested resources in Rails with forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form_for that operates on the following action/object:

```
   def new
     @student = Students.new
   end
```

In addition, the form is called from the following path

```
   schools/4/students/new
```

What is the best way to save the id of the school (4 in this case) to the new student record in the db? I cannot pre-load he @student object with it, since it is lost on the next request. I have used hidden_field in the form, but there must be a better way in rails. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`students` controller:

```
def new
  @school = School.find(params[:school_id])
  @student = @school.students.build
end

def create
  @school = School.find(params[:school_id])
  @student = @school.students.build(params[:student])
  if @student.save
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

form:

```
<%= form_for([@school, @student]) do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```